# Bootstrap changebody background color (using color picker)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, color-picker

I'm trying to implement a color picker on certain spots of my site. A simple div no prob, but the color picker for the bootstrap background is a problem.

Original Css background:

```
    html , body {
  background-color: grey !important;
}
```

Color picker Perfect situation (inside of my template/hbs file):

```
<style>
    body , html  {
      {{bind-attr style=background2}} !important;
    }
</style>
```

Why isn't this code working?

{{bind-attr style=background2}} = return 'background-color:'+this.get('color');

Answer (score 0):

Superficially, it’s not working because you’re trying to `bind-attr` but there’s no attribute to bind to. You could just do this:

```
{{background2}} !important;
```

That will output the value of `background2`, though in older versions of Ember, it will also output a `<script>` wrapper.

This is an unusual use of Handlebars and CSS. Maybe this would be better off as a call to jQuery triggered by a change to the colour field?